# Finding the nearest <li> tag closest to a form field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, that is dynamically generated by a Marketing SaaS we are using:

```
<li class='mktField'>
   <label>State:</label>
   <span class='mktInput'>
    <select class='mktFormSelect' name="State" id="State" size='1' tabIndex='10'>
    ......
    </select>
    <span class='mktFormMsg'></span>
   </span>
</li>
```

I have been tasked with setting up show and hide logic for the STATE field based on a country pick list value, this was not an issue. The issue I am having is how to "dynamically" add a class called "mktFormReq" to the code

```
<li class='mktField'>
```

I know you could do something like $("#ID").addClass but as you can see the code in question "" does not have an #ID to reference unfortunately.

My next idea was to look at using closest() or sibling() to find the closest "li" tag to the STATE field ID="State" and then going from there...

```
$("#State").closest("li").addClass("mktFormReq");
```

but I have not been having any luck there either. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your time and feedback...

Comment: Shouldn't `addClass("mktFormReq"");` be `addClass("mktFormReq");.`?

Comment: except a minor syntax error it looks fine `$("#State").closest('li').addClass("mktFormReq");` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fUyWJ/1/

Comment: @PaulDraper > you are right, my mistake as I typed out this question. I have corrected it. Thanks...

Comment: Are you *sure* that the class hasn't been added? Or that the code is being run? It looks right, and the JSFidlde by @ArunPJohny demonstrates it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny.... interesting, it looks like it works in jsfiddle. I must be doing something wrong on my end then. I will try again and report back. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Crazy!!! it works. Still weird that it was not working a bit again, I will QA it a bit more just to be safe.  Thank you for your time responding to my inquiry, much appreciated.

Comment: make sure that you have your code in dom ready handler

Comment: That I did..weird. At this time, I will chalk this mystery as solved. Thanks again for the help and feedback..